# How Libgdx delta time work?

Tags: java, libgdx, timedelta

Delta time is the value of the previous render call to the current render call, but I still want to know how it precisely works because when I use it I just do `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` . I would like to see a pseudo code on how it works or if it uses time stepping algorithm, or even a diagram. It bothers me that I use delta time a lot without even knowing how it works.

Comment: Libgdx is open source, you could look up the code yourself.

Comment: where exactly? I can't find the source code for libgdx

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34479099/2512687.

Comment: You are referring to the `Graphics` interface. So the Android backend implementation for example can be found [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidGraphics.java#L501).